# jQuery script run on (document).ready AND $(window).resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, ready

I'm javascript/jQuery clueless!

I have a script that is invoked with jQuery(document).ready which works great, I also want the script to update itself when the window is resized. The script is called like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#accordion').AccordionImageMenu({
      'openPc': <?PHP echo $params['openPc']; ?>,
      'width':<?PHP echo $params['width']; ?>, 
      'height':<?PHP echo $params['height']; ?>, 
      'effect': '<?PHP echo $params['effect']; ?>',
      'duration': <?PHP echo $params['duration']; ?>,
      'openItem': <?PHP echo ($params['keepMenuItemOpen'] ==1)? $openItem : "null"; ?>,
      'border' : <?PHP echo $params['border']; ?>,
      'color' : '<?PHP echo $params['color']; ?>',
      'position' : '<?PHP echo $params['position']; ?>',
      'fadeInTitle': <?PHP echo $params['fadeInTitle']; ?>
    }); 
});
```

I've tried

```
$(window).resize(function() {
accordionMenuSetting();
});
```

and

```
$(function() 
{$(window).resize(AccordionImageMenu).triggerHandler('resize'); });
```

and

```
    jQuery(window).on('resize', function($){
    $('#accordion').AccordionImageMenu({
      'openPc': <?PHP echo $params['openPc']; ?>,
      'width':<?PHP echo $params['width']; ?>, 
      'height':<?PHP echo $params['height']; ?>, 
      'effect': '<?PHP echo $params['effect']; ?>',
      'duration': <?PHP echo $params['duration']; ?>,
      'openItem': <?PHP echo ($params['keepMenuItemOpen'] ==1)? $openItem : "null"; ?>,
      'border' : <?PHP echo $params['border']; ?>,
      'color' : '<?PHP echo $params['color']; ?>',
      'position' : '<?PHP echo $params['position']; ?>',
      'fadeInTitle': <?PHP echo $params['fadeInTitle']; ?>
    }); 

});
```

but all come up with javascript errors.
Any ideas guys?  Thanks in advance! :-)

here is the full script

```
(function( $ ){

    function accordionMenuSetting(obj,settings) {       

            this.menuSettings = settings;
            this.menuAnimate = animate;         
            var _this = this;

            function animate(obj,i){                

                $.each(obj, function(j) {
                    var menuWidth = $('#accordion').width();
                    //claculate initial openDim based on percentage of menuWidth
                    var openDim = Math.round(menuWidth * (_this.menuSettings.openPc/100));
                    //calculate closedDim using initial openDim
                    var closedDim = Math.floor(  (  menuWidth-openDim - (_this.menuSettings.border*(obj.length-1)))/(obj.length-1)  );
                    //recalculate openDim based on closedDim.  this ensures that we use the full width and are pixel perfect (-1 just to make sure)
                    var openDim = menuWidth-(_this.menuSettings.border*(obj.length-1))- (closedDim*(obj.length-1))-1;
                    var neutralDim = Math.floor( (menuWidth- (_this.menuSettings.border*(obj.length-1)))/obj.length);
                    var remainder = menuWidth-(_this.menuSettings.border*(obj.length-1))- (neutralDim*obj.length);
                    var itemDim = closedDim;
                    if ( j == i ) {
                        itemDim = openDim;
                    }
                    if (typeof i == 'undefined') {
                        if (_this.menuSettings.openItem == null) { //keep active not set
                            if (j == (obj.length - 1)){ //if item is the last add the remainder to fill the space
                                itemDim = neutralDim + remainder;
                            }else{ //otherwise just use the neutral dimension
                                itemDim = neutralDim;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (_this.menuSettings.openItem == j) itemDim = openDim;
                        else itemDim = closedDim;
                    }

                    if (_this.menuSettings.position == 'vertical')
                        $(this).animate({'height':itemDim},_this.menuSettings.duration,_this.menuSettings.effect);
                    else 
                        $(this).animate({'width':itemDim},_this.menuSettings.duration,_this.menuSettings.effect);

                    var title = $('span',this);

                    title.stop(true,false);
                    if (_this.menuSettings.fadeInTitle >0 && title.length > 0) {
                        if (itemDim == openDim) {
                            if (_this.menuSettings.fadeInTitle ==2) title.animate({'opacity':0.7});
                            else title.animate({'opacity':0});      
                        } else {
                            if (_this.menuSettings.fadeInTitle ==2) title.animate({'opacity':0});
                            else title.animate({'opacity':0.7});
                        }
                    } else {
                        title.css("display", "none"); 
                    }

                });     

            }

            var $this = $('a',obj);
            var defaultViewPort = 940;
            var menuWidth = $('#accordion').width();
            var menuScale = menuWidth / defaultViewPort;
            var openDim = Math.round(menuWidth * (_this.menuSettings.openPc/100));
            //calculate closedDim using initial openDim
            var closedDim = Math.floor(  (  menuWidth-openDim - (_this.menuSettings.border*(obj.length-1)))/(obj.length-1)  );
            //recalculate openDim based on closedDim.  this ensures that we use the full width and are pixel perfect (-1 just to make sure)
            var openDim = menuWidth-(_this.menuSettings.border*(obj.length-1))- (closedDim*(obj.length-1))-1;

            _this.menuAnimate($this);

            var maxDim = closedDim*$this.length + _this.menuSettings.border*$this.length + 10;

            if (_this.menuSettings.position == 'vertical') 
                $(obj).css({'width':_this.menuSettings.width+'px','height':maxDim+'px'});
            else 
                $(obj).css({'height':_this.menuSettings.height * menuScale+'px','width':menuWidth+'px'});       


            $.each($this, function(i) { 

                ImgSrc = $('img',this).attr('src');
                $('img',this).hide();

                var borderBottomValue = 0;
                var borderRightValue = 'solid '+_this.menuSettings.border+'px '+_this.menuSettings.color;
                var aWidth = 'auto';            
                var aHeight = _this.menuSettings.height * menuScale+'px';
                if (_this.menuSettings.position == 'vertical') {

                    borderBottomValue = 'solid '+_this.menuSettings.border+'px '+_this.menuSettings.color;
                    borderRightValue = 0;
                    aWidth = _this.menuSettings.width+'px';             
                    aHeight = 'auto';               
                }   


                if ( i == ($this.length-1)) {
                    borderBottomValue = 0;
                    borderRightValue = 0;
                } 

                $(this).css({
                            'width': aWidth,
                            'height': aHeight,
                            'background-image':'url('+ImgSrc+')',
                            'background-size':'cover',
                            'background-color':_this.menuSettings.color,
                            'background-repeat':'no-repeat',
                            'border-bottom': borderBottomValue,
                            'border-right': borderRightValue                        
                            }).mouseenter(function() {
                                $this.stop(true,false);
                                _this.menuAnimate($this,i);
                            }); 

            });

            $(obj).mouseleave(function() {
                _this.menuAnimate($this);
            });


    }

    $.fn.AccordionImageMenu = function( options ) { 

        var settings = {
                        'openPc': 44,
                        'width':200,
                        'height':200,
                        'effect': 'swing',
                        'duration': 400,
                        'openItem': null,
                        'border': 2,
                        'color':'#000000', 
                        'position':'horizontal',
                        'fadeInTitle': true
                        };

        return this.each(function() {           
            $(this).addClass("aim");
            $('br',this).remove();
            if ( options ) $.extend( settings, options );
            var menu = new accordionMenuSetting(this,settings);
        });
    };

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Params width and height are set by php BEFORE the page is sent to the client. Once the client receives the page, all the dynamic code is handled by javascript.

Comment: Cheers for the reply, the params in question are not the ones I need to alter dynamically, here is a snippit of the script that I've managed to modify to be responsive [code]    var menuWidth = $('#accordion').width();
     //claculate initial openDim based on percentage of menuWidth
     var openDim = Math.round(menuWidth * (_this.menuSettings.openPc/100));

[/code] I just need the script to re evaluate [code]var menuWidth = $('#accordion').width();[/code]

Comment: It is not clear from the question what you want to do. Resize the accordion? How? The code in comments is difficult to read. What is `accordionMenuSetting` doing?

Comment: I've added the full script to the original post for you to see.  Basically I need the script to re-run on window resize so as it can re-scale to accordion (the original script was based on fixed width, I've made it responsive by using var menuWidth = $('#accordion').width();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Instead of adding the $(window).resize(function() { to the calling page I added it into the included JS file. This way I was able to 'see' the trigger and act upon it. To act upon it I created a new function called resize which updated the parameters I needed.  Down side:  if you manually size the browser window with the mouse it resized the menu 1 pixel at a time which is not perfect and does occasionally fall over.  If you simply go from one size to another then it works fine.  here is the finished code.  I'm sure there is a better way (hint hint) but I've exhausted my own knowledge.

```
    (function( $ ){

    function accordionMenuSetting(obj,settings) {       
            this.menuSettings = settings;
            this.menuAnimate = animate;         
            this.menuResize = resize;           
            var _this = this;

            function animate(obj,i){                

                $.each(obj, function(j) {
                    var menuWidth = $('#accordion-box').width();
                    //console.log ("width = "+$('#accordion-box').width());
                    //claculate initial openDim based on percentage of menuWidth
                    var openDim = Math.round(menuWidth * (_this.menuSettings.openPc/100));
                    //calculate closedDim using initial openDim
                    var closedDim = Math.floor(  (  menuWidth-openDim - (_this.menuSettings.border*(obj.length-1)))/(obj.length-1)  );
                    //recalculate openDim based on closedDim.  this ensures that we use the full width and are pixel perfect (-1 just to make sure)
                    var openDim = menuWidth-(_this.menuSettings.border*(obj.length-1))- (closedDim*(obj.length-1))-1;
                    var neutralDim = Math.floor( (menuWidth- (_this.menuSettings.border*(obj.length-1)))/obj.length);
                    var remainder = menuWidth-(_this.menuSettings.border*(obj.length-1))- (neutralDim*obj.length);
                    var itemDim = closedDim;
                    if ( j == i ) {
                        itemDim = openDim;
                    }
                    if (typeof i == 'undefined') {
                        if (_this.menuSettings.openItem == null) { //keep active not set
                            if (j == (obj.length - 1)){ //if item is the last add the remainder to fill the space
                                itemDim = neutralDim + remainder;
                            }else{ //otherwise just use the neutral dimension
                                itemDim = neutralDim;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (_this.menuSettings.openItem == j) itemDim = openDim;
                        else itemDim = closedDim;
                    }

                    if (_this.menuSettings.position == 'vertical')
                        $(this).animate({'height':itemDim},_this.menuSettings.duration,_this.menuSettings.effect);
                    else 
                        $(this).animate({'width':itemDim},_this.menuSettings.duration,_this.menuSettings.effect);

                    var title = $('span',this);

                    title.stop(true,false);
                    if (_this.menuSettings.fadeInTitle >0 && title.length > 0) {
                        if (itemDim == openDim) {
                            if (_this.menuSettings.fadeInTitle ==2) title.animate({'opacity':0.7});
                            else title.animate({'opacity':0});      
                        } else {
                            if (_this.menuSettings.fadeInTitle ==2) title.animate({'opacity':0});
                            else title.animate({'opacity':0.7});
                        }
                    } else {
                        title.css("display", "none"); 
                    }

                });     

            }
            function resize(obj,i){
                var defaultViewPort = 940;
                var menuWidth = $('#accordion-box').width();
                var menuScale = menuWidth / defaultViewPort;
                console.log ("menuscale=" + menuScale);
                var openDim = Math.round(menuWidth * (_this.menuSettings.openPc/100));
                //calculate closedDim using initial openDim
                var closedDim = Math.floor(  (  menuWidth-openDim - (_this.menuSettings.border*(obj.length-1)))/(obj.length-1)  );
                //recalculate openDim based on closedDim.  this ensures that we use the full width and are pixel perfect (-1 just to make sure)
                var openDim = menuWidth-(_this.menuSettings.border*(obj.length-1))- (closedDim*(obj.length-1))-1;

                _this.menuAnimate($this);

                var maxDim = closedDim*$this.length + _this.menuSettings.border*$this.length + 10;

                if (_this.menuSettings.position == 'vertical') 
                    $(obj).css({'width':_this.menuSettings.width+'px','height':maxDim+'px'});
                else 
                    $(obj).css({'height':_this.menuSettings.height * menuScale+'px','width':menuWidth+'px'});       


                $.each($this, function(i) { 
                    var aWidth = 'auto';            
                    var aHeight = _this.menuSettings.height * menuScale+'px';
                    if (_this.menuSettings.position == 'vertical') {

                        aWidth = _this.menuSettings.width+'px';             
                        aHeight = 'auto';               
                    }   
                    $(this).css({
                        'width': aWidth,
                        'height': aHeight
                    }); 

                })
            };

            var $this = $('a',obj);
            var defaultViewPort = 940;
            var menuWidth = $('#accordion-box').width();
            var menuScale = menuWidth / defaultViewPort;
            console.log ("menuscale=" + menuScale);
            var openDim = Math.round(menuWidth * (_this.menuSettings.openPc/100));
            //calculate closedDim using initial openDim
            var closedDim = Math.floor(  (  menuWidth-openDim - (_this.menuSettings.border*(obj.length-1)))/(obj.length-1)  );
            //recalculate openDim based on closedDim.  this ensures that we use the full width and are pixel perfect (-1 just to make sure)
            var openDim = menuWidth-(_this.menuSettings.border*(obj.length-1))- (closedDim*(obj.length-1))-1;

            _this.menuAnimate($this);

            var maxDim = closedDim*$this.length + _this.menuSettings.border*$this.length + 10;

            if (_this.menuSettings.position == 'vertical') 
                $(obj).css({'width':_this.menuSettings.width+'px','height':maxDim+'px'});
            else 
                $(obj).css({'height':_this.menuSettings.height * menuScale+'px','width':menuWidth+'px'});       


            $.each($this, function(i) { 

                ImgSrc = $('img',this).attr('src');
                $('img',this).hide();

                var borderBottomValue = 0;
                var borderRightValue = 'solid '+_this.menuSettings.border+'px '+_this.menuSettings.color;
                var aWidth = 'auto';            
                var aHeight = _this.menuSettings.height * menuScale+'px';
                if (_this.menuSettings.position == 'vertical') {

                    borderBottomValue = 'solid '+_this.menuSettings.border+'px '+_this.menuSettings.color;
                    borderRightValue = 0;
                    aWidth = _this.menuSettings.width+'px';             
                    aHeight = 'auto';               
                }   


                if ( i == ($this.length-1)) {
                    borderBottomValue = 0;
                    borderRightValue = 0;
                } 

                $(this).css({
                            'width': aWidth,
                            'height': aHeight,
                            'background-image':'url('+ImgSrc+')',
                            'background-size':'cover',
                            'background-color':_this.menuSettings.color,
                            'background-repeat':'no-repeat',
                            'border-bottom': borderBottomValue,
                            'border-right': borderRightValue                        
                            }).mouseenter(function() {
                                $this.stop(true,false);
                                _this.menuAnimate($this,i);
                            }); 

            });

                $(window).resize(function() {
                    _this.menuResize(obj);
                });


            $(obj).mouseleave(function() {
                _this.menuAnimate($this);
            });

    }

    $.fn.AccordionImageMenu = function( options ) { 

        var settings = {
                        'openPc': 44,
                        'width':200,
                        'height':200,
                        'effect': 'swing',
                        'duration': 400,
                        'openItem': null,
                        'border': 2,
                        'color':'#000000', 
                        'position':'horizontal',
                        'fadeInTitle': true
                        };

        return this.each(function() {           
            $(this).addClass("aim");
            $('br',this).remove();
            if ( options ) $.extend( settings, options );
            var menu = new accordionMenuSetting(this,settings);
        });
    };

})( jQuery );
```